# Remote controlling an ATX power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, control, atx, remote

First of all i hope you will all excuse my spelling as i am Dyslexic.

I have two computer cases one is fully outfitted and has a sas expander to run 16 hard drives in it with a breakout to a backplane which is the cabled to a breakout on the 2nd case which goes to a 2nd sas expander which is plugged into a powered pcie mining board connected to an atx power supply for power and connects another 12 sas hdd's. There is no computer in this 2nd case.
What i am wanting to do is when the power button is turned on, on the first computer have it turn on the power of the power supply in the 2nd case and in the event that the computer is shutdown in the first case as soon as the power goes off have it shutdown the power supply in the other case. it would also be nice but not absolutely nessesary if this could also support sleep modes.

Can anybody point me in the right direction electronically as  to how to acheive this?

Cheers.

Comment: Your dyslexia **really** doesn't show! This is very solid spelling :)

Comment: Thanks, I do my best but I initially failed school certificate english with 38%, after learning I had Dyselxia - I just thought I was dumb I returned to school as an adult student after learning some tricks and scraped through with a pass at 62%

Comment: Well, I know this can't retroactively help you, but maybe this perspective helps you now: For me, the fact that you have Dyslexia definitely has no negative consequence for your ability to talk with me. So, I'm 100% sure that you're the opposite of dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you investigate simply driving the PS_ON# signal to both ATX power supplies from the same source. The source would come from the motherboard in the box with the computer.

This diagram shows how it would be interconnected:

[image]

This will result in when the soft power switch in the computer subsystem is activated the PS_ON from the motherboard will activate to a low level and both power supplies will turn on at the same time.

Not that at the disk box you would just connect the PS_ON to the ATX power supply. If there is some existing drive of that wire at the disk connections end of the cable you would leave it open.

This should work correctly for the sleep support and would even support turning things back on should there be a wake event at the computer board such as a mouse move, wake on LAN or a soft power button press.

Comment: I like this idea as it seems relatively simple, I do have a couple of questions though. 1) Will connecting the PS_ON and GND connections as indicated effect either power supply in the respect of trying to ramp up or down the values of those connections if they don't match exactly in voltage or current?                                                      2) Should the connections for those lines be optically isolated as suggested by Justme?

Comment: I should have asked too what about the power good signal for the 2nd supply - do I need to do something with that to stop the supply from shutting down?

Comment: The two PS_ON signals are inputs to the two power supplies. Each power supply will typically have a pullup resistor to the 5V_STBY within the power supply on this input. The motherboard will typically have a circuit to pull the PS_ON signals to GND to turn on the supplies. That driver may be a small NPN transistor collector, an N-FET drain or an open drain gate of some type. As long as the GND connections of the two ATX power supplies are common there should be no problem with connecting the two PS_ON signals as I described. (continued)

Comment: (continued from above)  The PS_PWROK signal from the second power supply can be left to connect where ever it currently connects in the disk array box (if it connects to anything at all). I see no advantage what so ever to isolate using a relay or opto-coupler.

Comment: This would not be my first suggestion. It would be better with some isolation like two schottky diodes. While the PS_ON signals are inputs, their actual implementations can vary between PSU models and manufacturers. Connecting PS_ON wires together means there are two inputs loads for the motherboard to drive. But each PSU will pull its own PS_ON signal high to its own standby 5V supply. The voltages have tolerance, so current may flow from higher voltage supply to lower voltage supply via the PS_ON pins. When one PSU has mains unplugged, it might clamp PS_ON to GND, turning the other PSU on.

Comment: So that would be one Shottky per case then as either power supply plug could be disconnected. would it be possible to opto isolate them instead? then it would be certain that one supply could not effect the load values of the other would it not? My understanding of electronics in limited but if my understanding is correct an optoisolator is like an led and light detector in one unit that voltage and current cant jump, only light.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty simple. To turn on the second power supply, you just need to connect the green wire (PS_ON) to ground. And you need to do that when the first power supply is on, i.e. there is voltages present on the output. There are various ways you can achieve that, for example a relay, transistor or optocoupler.